# Netbeans: How to change the automatically generated launch.html when web start is activated?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, java-web-start

When activating the Web Start in Netbeans for a project, it automatically builds  a launch.jnlp and a launch.html

is there a way to change this generated launch.html?

edit: change the html code of the page

Comment: Change it how, specifically?

Comment: edited to be more specific about what i want to change